# could not load file or assembly microsoft.visualstudio.editor.razor 2017 for ASP.NET.Core application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core

when I opened my view or .cshtml page in my mvc project,

It shows the error in the alert box, "could not load file or assembelly Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Razor, Verrsion=2.1.2.0[image]".
Can any one please in my issue,

Thanks

I followed instrction on this link but not worked.
[https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/194267/the-document-cannot-be-opened-it-has-been-renamed.html][2]

Comment: I think you need to add some more info. How is anyone supposed to help you when we can't see what you have done? Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your question.

Answer (score 3):

Issue is raised when Razorlanguage services is disables.We can Enable Razorlanguage services through visualstudio -->Tools -->Extensions and updates -->  Search for Razorlanguageservices enable.

Answer (score 1):

1)Close VS

2)Delete the content of %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache

Note:- here 14.0 visual studio version may be in your system different like
15,15.0_867fe6fa etc

3)Open VS

its work for me